# All columns not inserted in the database

Tags: php

Whenever i try to insert more than one row in the database table only 1 row gets inserted. i have tried all the methods and still cannot insert all rows at once. This is my HTML code

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
include ('includes/workprogress_func.php');
?>

<body>

</ul>
</div>
<div id="rightcol">
  <div id="Content" align="center">
<h1 align="center">Workplan Progress Form</h1>
<div id="table1" class="container" align="left">    
            <form name="form1" action="" method="post">
            <table width="398" height="118" border="0" align="left" >

              <td>

                <tr>
                        <td > <p>Division Name:</p> </td>
                        <td> <input name="divisionname" type="text" value="" /></td>
                </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><p>Division Chief: </p></td>
                        <td>   
                        <input type="text" name="divisionchief"   /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><p> Period:  </p> </td>
                        <td>  
                        <input type="text" name="period"   /></td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><p> Month:</p>  </td>
                        <td>  

                        <input type="month" name="month"  > </td>
                    </tr>


</table>
                </div>
                <div id="table2">
                <table border="1" align="center" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1"  >
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="2" align="center"> SN </td>
                <td rowspan="2" align="center"> Activity Name </td>
                <td rowspan="2" align="center" > Unit </td>
                <td rowspan="2" align="center"> Weightage </td>
                <td colspan="4" align="center"> Performance Indicators(Percentage)</td>
                <td colspan="3" align="center"> Performance Achievement </td>
                <td colspan="2" align="center"> Indicator Measurement Basis </td>
             <tr>
                <td align="center">100 </td>
                <td align="center"> 75</td>
                <td align="center"> 50 </td>
                <td align="center"> <50 </td>
                <td align="center">Measurement </td>
                <td align="center"> Score</td>
                <td align="center"> Progress </td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td width:60px > 1</td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="activityname[]" style="width:100px"/> </td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="unit[]"  style="width:50px" /> </td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="weightage[]" style="width:80px"/> </td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="per100[]" style="width:50px"/> </td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="per75[]"   style="width:50px" /> </td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="per50[]"   style="width:50px"/> </td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="perless50[]"   style="width:50px"/> </td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="measurement[]"   style="width:100px"/> </td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="score[]"   style="width:50px"/> </td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="progress[]"   style="width:80px"/> </td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="indicatormeasure[]"   style="width:150px"/> </td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
                <td width:60px > 2</td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="activityname[]" style="width:100px"/> </td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="unit[]"  style="width:50px" /> </td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="weightage[]" style="width:80px"/> </td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="per100[]" style="width:50px"/> </td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="per75[]"   style="width:50px" /> </td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="per50[]"   style="width:50px"/> </td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="perless50[]"   style="width:50px"/> </td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="measurement[]"   style="width:100px"/> </td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="score[]"   style="width:50px"/> </td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="progress[]"   style="width:80px"/> </td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="indicatormeasure[]"   style="width:150px"/> </td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
                <td width:60px > 3</td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="activityname[]" style="width:100px"/> </td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="unit[]"  style="width:50px" /> </td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="weightage[]" style="width:80px"/> </td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="per100[]" style="width:50px"/> </td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="per75[]"   style="width:50px" /> </td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="per50[]"   style="width:50px"/> </td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="perless50[]"   style="width:50px"/> </td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="measurement[]"   style="width:100px"/> </td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="score[]"   style="width:50px"/> </td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="progress[]"   style="width:80px"/> </td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="indicatormeasure[]"   style="width:150px"/> </td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
                <td width:60px > 3</td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="activityname[]" style="width:100px"/> </td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="unit[]"  style="width:50px" /> </td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="weightage[]" style="width:80px"/> </td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="per100[]" style="width:50px"/> </td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="per75[]"   style="width:50px" /> </td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="per50[]"   style="width:50px"/> </td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="perless50[]"   style="width:50px"/> </td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="measurement[]"   style="width:100px"/> </td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="score[]"   style="width:50px"/> </td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="progress[]"   style="width:80px"/> </td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="indicatormeasure[]"   style="width:150px"/> </td>
              </tr>

              </table>
              </br>
            </div>  


                    <div align="center"> <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" /> 





                    <label>
                    <input name="h" type="hidden" id="h" value="0" />
                    </label>
                    </form>

                </div>
                </div>
                </div>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is my PHP code for insertion

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

include('includes/connect.php');
$num =  $_POST['h'];
for ($i=0; $i<=$num; $i++)
{
$divisionname=$_POST['divisionname'];
$divisionchief=$_POST['divisionchief'];
$period=$_POST['period'];
$month=$_POST['month'];
$activityname=$_POST['activityname'][$i];
$unit=$_POST['unit'][$i];
$weightage=$_POST['weightage'][$i];
$per100=$_POST['per100'][$i];
$per75=$_POST['per75'][$i];
$per50=$_POST['per50'][$i];
$perless50=$_POST['perless50'][$i];
$measurement=$_POST['measurement'][$i];
$score=$_POST['score'][$i];
$progress=$_POST['progress'][$i];
$indicatormeasure=$_POST['indicatormeasure'][$i];


$sql="INSERT INTO `workplan_progress` (`name`, `chief`, `timePeriod`, `workMonth`, `activity_names`, `workUnit`, `workWeightage`, `percent_100`, `percent_75`, `percent_50`, `percent_less50`, `Measure`, `Score`, `Progress`, `indicator_measure`) VALUES ('$divisionname', '$divisionchief', '$period', '$month', '$activityname', '$unit', '$weightage', '$per100', '$per75', '$per50', '$perless50', '$measurement', '$score', '$progress', '$indicatormeasure')";
    mysql_query($sql);
    //echo "$sql";

    //header("location:workplan.php");
    }
    echo"This information has been added to the database."; 
}
?>
```

Can somebody please help me out!!!

Comment: One column or one row?

Comment: You are not doing any sort of escaping. Does any of the data contain an apostrophe?

Comment: What's the value of `$_POST['h']`?

Comment: what you are getting while `echo $query` ?

Comment: The value of $_POST['h'] is 0. it is a label below the submit button.

Comment: While echo$query, I am getting the values of only 1st row.

Comment: This code has big vulnerability in the matter of SQL injection, and also can be tricked to exceed the memory limit of the server if one changes the value of hidden field named `h`

Comment: Can anyone point out what's wrong in my code??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<input name="h" type="hidden" id="h" value="0" />

$num =  $_POST['h'];
for ($i=0; $i<=$num; $i++)
```

value = 0 and 0<=0 is only one loop ;-)

you set in html h to 0, so $num is allways 0.
you can set $num to the count of submited rows by

```
$num = count($_POST['activityname']);
```

but that works only if you fill out the activityname field or you can set the $num to the count of your rows.

Comment: So should i assign the value to 1 or $i to 1??

Comment: the simpelst way is to set the quantity on the post variable,
so change to $num = count($_POST['divisionname']);

Comment: I did not quite get it. What should i change??

Comment: i just saw that you use divisionname only once, so try it with activityname
$num = count($_POST['activityname']); or set $num to the count of rows

Comment: DO i have to do this for each of the variables??

Comment: i think you don't understand your code
for ($i=0; $i<=$num; $i++)
the problem that your code only runs 1 is, that the variable num is wrong. If you set $num to 2 your loop runs 3 times (0,1,2)

Comment: I want the loop to be executed as much times as the rows of data i submit in the form

Comment: yes then you can take a varibale of the rows like i say
$num = count($_POST['activityname']);
but you should change <= to < else you has 1 count too much